# Ranking of single datapoint against reference dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following hypothetical dataframe:

```
data = {'score1':[60, 30, 80, 120],
        'score2':[20, 21, 19, 18],
       'score3':[12, 43, 71, 90]}
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# calculating the ranks
df['score1_rank'] = df['score1'].rank(pct = True)
df['score2_rank'] = df['score2'].rank(pct = True)
df['score3_rank'] = df['score3'].rank(pct = True)
```

I then have individual datapoints I would like to to rank against the references, for example:

```
data_to_test = {'score1':[12],
        'score2':[4],
       'score3':[6]}
```

How could I compare these new values against this reference?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is your question exactly? what do you want to do with the dictionary? `How could I compare these new values against this reference` - which new value

Comment: @anky there are 2 sets of data in the question, the dictionary used to make the dataframe and the second dictionary I would like to compare (although these are abstractions, the second comparison set could be any value):                                          
As presented in the question:                                                                                                                                           I then have individual datapoints I would like to to rank against the references, for example:

data = {'score1':[12],
        'score2':[4],
       'score3':[6]}

Comment: What do you expect as result? For example for `data = [50, 22, 88]`

Comment: @Corralien yes, exactly, something along those lines. I just don't know how to use the reference data against any given individual datapoint